# EpiTwitter Now Returning 'Sorry, that page does not exist', Error Code 34, Recommended Changes Don't Work

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

[twitter api always give "Sorry, that page does not exist" error for deleted tweets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186068/twitter-api-always-give-sorry-that-page-does-not-exist-error-for-deleted-twee)

[Using Twitter API has started giving a Sorry Page does not exist error even though it worked earlier on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827627/using-twitter-api-has-started-giving-a-sorry-page-does-not-exist-error-even-thou)

[Twitter 404 - message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905600/twitter-404-messagesorry-that-page-does-not-exist-code34)

Hi, I have read the above questions but the suggestions don't fix it for me.

I have a page on my site that lets users authenticate my twitter application that then posts a tweet on their timeline.

The API is returning `{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}` in the JSON response.

If I follow the suggestions I have read in other questions, changing the EpiTwitter class from

```
const EPITWITTER_SIGNATURE_METHOD = 'HMAC-SHA1';
protected $requestTokenUrl = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
protected $accessTokenUrl = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token';
protected $authorizeUrl = 'http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize';
protected $apiUrl = 'http://twitter.com';
```

to

```
const EPITWITTER_SIGNATURE_METHOD = 'HMAC-SHA1';
protected $requestTokenUrl= 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';
protected $accessTokenUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token';
protected $authorizeUrl   = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize';
protected $authenticateUrl= 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate';
protected $apiUrl         = 'https://api.twitter.com';
protected $searchUrl      = 'http://search.twitter.com';
```

doesn't work either, when the login link is generated by the app it goes to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token= which says there was no request token for this page.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies,

I knew the Twitter API had changed but didn't see that the class files had been updated.

For anyone else having the same problem simply update your files from here:

https://github.com/jmathai/twitter-async

Please note that there is a new file called EpiSequence.php (although I'm not sure what it's purpose is yet).

At first I thought the files hadn't been updated to work with the new api url's because I couldn't see anything that showed signs of a recent commit.